# Ubuntu: Updating Mapnik from 2.2.0 to 3.x, complications?

Tags: ubuntu, mapnik, update

I'm wanting to upgrade Mapnik on a production system from 2.2.0 to 3.x to take advantage of improvements to data-driven rendering. Fortunately the [install instructions for Ubuntu](https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/wiki/UbuntuInstallation) have been updated very recently (11 days ago as of this post), however I'm wondering what happens if I run the installation on a system with an existing install. Has anyone tried this?

We're using TileStache to render several map tile endpoints, most importantly some UTFGrid json files, and I am concerned that I will pollute the system— maybe irreparably!—by running the install.

Can anyone comment on what might happen if I run the latest Mapnik installation on a system with an existing, properly functioning install?

---

**[Edit 8/22/2018]**

I got through the transition on a test server and incorporated my prior edits into an thorough answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remembered I had a tiny Rackspace instance that I setup once upon a time to test code portability. It has a nearly identical version of our webstack, particularly the Ubuntu and Mapnik versions, so it made a reasonable test bed to experiment with moving from 2.2.x to 3.x.

In a nutshell, this was a complicated transition that involved sincere troubleshooting, research, stack resets, some code modifications to XML stylesheets, and although I got things working again, my confidence is a little weak. Were this a production system, downtime would have been considerable.

What follows is a list of the 'gotchas' I encountered trying to nail down the build dependencies (c++ compiler version, clang version, git version, etc.) and some configuration/usage issues I ran into after the fact. Hopefully consulting this list can help avoid some unnecessary downtime and hasten the transitional process..

---

In attempting to install and configure Mapnik on Ubuntu using the official instructions [found here](https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/wiki/UbuntuInstallation#install-mapnik-from-source), under the heading "Install Mapnik from Source", I suggest augmenting those instructions with information provided below. FWIW this is relative to Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS.

First, before installing or uninstalling anything Mapnik..

**1) Compiler**

Update the g++ compiler. Building Mapnik requires c14 compiler features, and you'll be unable to build if your compiler fails the dependencies/versioning test. In your terminal, type `g++ --version` and if your version is below 4.9 go ahead and update. I used the guide found [here](http://scholtyssek.org/blog/2015/06/11/install-gcc-with-c14-support-on-ubuntumint/), specifically these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install g++-4.9
sudo ln -f -s /usr/bin/g++-4.9 /usr/bin/g++
```

**2) Fix Clang**

I had an issue with `clang` versioning and fixed it by adapting the instructions found [here](https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/wiki/UbuntuInstallation#source-install-of-mapnik-master-3x) under the heading "Source install of Mapnik Master (3.x)" I changed all instances of `3.6` to `3.8`, and based on an error/warning I received on my fist install attempt, I added the `--force-yes` flag to the actual `apt-get` install instruction. These are the terminal commands I used to install the proper `clang` version:

```
CLANG_VERSION=3.8
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test;
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://llvm.org/apt/precise/ llvm-toolchain-precise-${CLANG_VERSION} main";
wget -O - http://llvm.org/apt/llvm-snapshot.gpg.key|sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update -y
#### I had to add "--force-yes" to fix this install command:
#### sudo apt-get install -y clang-3.8;
sudo apt-get install -y --force-yes clang-3.8;
export CXX="clang++-3.8" && export CC="clang-3.8";
```

When you're finished, you should be able to type `echo $CXX` and get terminal output `clang++-3.8` or `echo $CC` and get `clang-3.8`, respectively. If you don't get these responses, something may fail during a later configure/build step.

**3) Upgrade Git**

I initially ran into a `git` usage error related to use of a `-C` parameter the first time I executed the `source bootstrap.sh` command, which appears to establish some traits of the build environment. Googling for solutions, it seems I had two options, either [modify the bootstrap.sh file](https://bugs.python.org/issue30411) by replacing instances of `-C` with `--git-dir`, as apparently these have equivalent functionality, or [upgrade git](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/170831).

You can run `git --version` in terminal—mine was `1.7.9.5` prior to upgrading. After upgrading, my version increased to `2.18.0`, and the `-C` parameter issue disappeared. Upgrading was this easy:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa -y
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git -y
```

**4) libgdal.la not found**

I forgot where I encountered this issue, during either `source bootstrap.sh` or possibly the `./configure..` step. But I got the error:

```
# Error found:
# /home/buildnik/mapnik/mason_packages/linux-x86_64/libgdal/2.1.3/lib/libgdal.la not found
```

Based on the instructions under [Set up build environment](https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/wiki/UbuntuInstallation#set-up-build-environment), manually installing `libgdal1-dev` like this fixed the issue:

```
apt-get install libgdal1-dev
```

I suspect you can do this before removing old Mapnik or starting any of the formal installation steps.

**5) Honorable mention, severity unknown**

When executing `make test`, I got errors like:

```
test/unit/datasource/postgis.cpp:87:
warning:
  Can't run postgis.input tests - check postmaster is running and accessible
```

and..

```
ROR (Postgis Plugin: FATAL:  role "root" does not exist
```

They might have been related to my installed PostGRESql version (9.1), which works fine. I never resolved these errors/warnings, but my Mapnik build/install seems to be working okay in spite of them. FWIW, elsewhere in the instructions, a note points Ubuntu 14.04 users toward pg 9.3.

**6) Actually install Mapnik**

At this point I *uninstalled* Mapnik, then started my fresh build/install. I'm not sure if it's 100% essential to remove your old Mapnik first, but I saw instructions recommending it, from Dane no less. So I removed Mapnik as my first step.

Everything went like this:

```
sudo apt-get purge libmapnik* mapnik-* python-mapnik
cd /home
mkdir buildnik
cd buildnik
git clone https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik mapnik --depth 10
cd mapnik
git submodule update --init
sudo apt-get install python zlib1g-dev clang make pkg-config curl
source bootstrap.sh
./configure CUSTOM_CXXFLAGS="-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0" CXX=${CXX} CC=${CC}
make
make test
sudo make install
```

A few of these steps, particularly the `make` instruction, took quite awhile, probably because my server instance is tiny. But knowing this, at least don't expect just one or two minutes of downtime. Unless you play by wild-west rules, you'll want to do this upgrade during a reasonable maintenance window.

---

At this point I ran into issues importing Mapnik libs in Python. TileStache was throwing errors at Apache, which is how I noticed.

**7) Install Mapnik Python bindings**

First [install the Mapnik Python bindings](https://mapnik.org/news/python-bindings). It's super easy. Just make sure you have `pip` >= 1.4, which has something to do with the Python Wheels dependency. Use `pip --version` to check. Mine's pip 7.1.2, so I suspect pip version is a non-issue:

```
pip install mapnik
```

This will probably fix the issue.

**8) Check `ldconfig`**

You might not need to do this but [the troubleshooting instructions](https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/wiki/InstallationTroubleshooting#the-libmapnik-shared-library-is-not-found) call for a tweak to the LD config in the case of Python not finding Mapnik. I deviated slightly from the troubleshooting recommendation, based mostly on what I read [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1815240). Rather than add a path directly to `/etc/ld.so.conf`, I created a new file in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` and added my path values there, like this:

```
cd /etc/ld.so.conf.d
touch niklib.conf
vi niklib.conf
```

Inside `niklib.cof`, add the following three lines:

```
# Required to link Mapnik libs
/usr/local/lib
/usr/local/lib64
```

After saving the file, update the environment with:

```
ldconfig -v
```

Note: If you `dir /etc/ld.so.conf.d` and see `libc.conf`, and if you `vi /etc/ld.so.conf.d/libc.conf` and see `/usr/local/lib` in that file, then you can skip this step #8, as your LD environment should already reference the necessary paths.

**9) Mapnik XML design files (i.e. XML map stylesheets)**

At this point I could launch Python and import Mapnik libs, but TileStache still wasn't rendering (most) tiles! By tailing the Apache log like this:

```
tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

I noticed errors popping up that looked like this:

```
failed to initialize projection with: '&google_mercator;'
```

This took awhile to understand and fix. It turns out default build-from-source configurations for Mapnik use a different XML library (`rapidxml`) than was used for some turnkey builds (`libxml2`), which I suspect a lot of people used around the 2.x release, most likely because those builds were promoted by one or more popular tutorials. The issue stems from so-called XML Entities, and it seems the (older?) Open Street Map (OMS) XML map designs used these XML entities, which further propagated this approach. You can find a longer discussion of this [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/293654/4968).

As it happened, *some of* my own map designs were using XML entities to set the map srs/projection attributes, which were the source of my Apache errors. I got a lucky break by noticing that my UTFGrid tiles were actually rendering, and a close inspection of the map designs revealed a different manner of setting the map srs/projection. As such, I was able to make small changes to these XML files to eliminate the last of my show-stopping errors, bringing full functionality back online.

**9a) What I did..**

Basically I looked through my map files and changed every instance of something like this (notice the `ENTITY` tag):

```
<!DOCTYPE Map [
  <!ENTITY google_mercator "+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs +over">]>

<Map srs="&google_mercator;">
...
```

..to simply, this:

```
<!DOCTYPE Map>
<Map srs="+init=epsg:3857">
...
```

**9b) What you may prefer..**

Optionally, if you need to fix/check A LOT of XML designs, you might want to check out `xmllint`, which has an option to sanitize XML Entities, and which you can incorporate into automation and use to mass-render all your XML files, then overwrite them into place with a single command.

Try calling `xmllint --version`. If you don't get any feedback, you can install the utility like this:

```
apt-get install libxml2-utils
```

Once you've got it installed, look at a problematic XML file (one that contains an ENTITY tag), make a copy of it, and run xmllint on it like this to see how it morphs the code:

```
xmllint --noent parcels_bk.xml
```

It'll pump XML right into the console, and you'll see those ENTITY tags replaced by their actual values.

**10) Honorable mention, inconsequential (mod_python version)**

At this point I cleared my Apache log file, rebooted, then tailed the log to see if any more errors were appearing. Of course on serious systems it's better to make a backup of this file before clearing it:

```
> /var/log/apache2/error.log
reboot
tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

When I did this I saw the following (note mention of "version mismatch"):

```
[Tue Aug 21 19:12:15 2018] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Aug 21 19:14:08 2018] [error] python_init: Python version mismatch, expected '2.7.2+', found '2.7.3'.
[Tue Aug 21 19:14:09 2018] [error] python_init: Python executable found '/usr/bin/python'.
[Tue Aug 21 19:14:09 2018] [error] python_init: Python path being used '/usr/lib/python2.7/:/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-

linux2:/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk:/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old:/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload'.
[Tue Aug 21 19:14:09 2018] [notice] mod_python: Creating 8 session mutexes based on 150 max processes and 0 max threads.
[Tue Aug 21 19:14:09 2018] [notice] mod_python: using mutex_directory /tmp
[Tue Aug 21 19:14:09 2018] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.26 with Suhosin-Patch mod_python/3.3.1 

Python/2.7.3 mod_wsgi/3.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

I was concerned this might have been related to my build or my bindings, etc., but turns out it's related to `mod_python`, which TileStache uses portage internet requests and responses through Apache. Since my install is working, I chose not to rock the boat any further and stopped there. ..I probably had this error/warning all along. But if you get this error and you're so inclined, it seems [removing and reinstalling mod_python may be a solution](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2220016):

```
apt-get remove libapache2-mod-python libapache2-mod-wsgi
apt-get build-dep libapache2-mod-python libapache2-mod-wsgi
```

That concludes my experience going from a working Mapnik 2.2.x to a working Mapnik 3.x on Ubuntu 12.04. Hopefully this helps someone transition quicker than I was able to and avoid some of the frustrations.

....finally, since these systems can be so very different: GOOD. LUCK.

Comment: Any reason you stick to Ubuntu precise? 18.04 is the current LTS, and has Mapnik 3 already in the main repo.

Comment: @AndreJ I'd forgotten about this. In a nutshell, that 12.04 system is a production box that shoulders about 50% of our workload. (The other %50 is an even older 10.04!) I inherited both and don't have any experience doing OS-level upgrades on live environments. I feel like venturing into those waters could create a huge mess if I get unlucky. But these two are living on borrowed time at this point—we've got two new instances lined up to replace them, it's just a matter of installing, configuring, and migrating code